# Finding the sides of a Triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

So i've tried this question for a while now, but can't seem to get an answer. I tried to equate z but don't know how to proceed. Can someone help?

In△XYZ, the measure of∠XZY is 90. Also, YZ=x cm, XZ=y cm, and hypotenuse
XY has length z cm. Further, the perimeter of △XYZ is P cm and the area of △XYZ
is A cmsq .

Determine all possible integer values of x, y and z for which A = 3P .

Comment: The area of $A$ is $xy/2$, and $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ so you need to solve $3 (x + y + \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} ) = xy/2$.

Comment: We have
$$x+y + z = P$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = z^2$$
So, $A = 3P$ when
$$\frac{xy}{6} = x + y + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
Since $x,y,z\in \Bbb Z$, $6|xy$. Hopefully someone can take it from here.

Comment: This reduces to one branch of the hyperbola $(x-12)(y-12)=72.$

Answer (score 1):

Using $A=rs$, $P=2s$, where $s=$ semiperimeter and $r=$ inradius, given condition reduces to
$$rs=3\cdot 2s\Rightarrow r=6$$

From the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#Inradius_and_circumradius), $x+y-z=2r$, we get
$$x+y=z+12$$

which leads to
$$(x-12)(y-12)=72$$

for which there are six integral solutions.

Comment: You're missing $(18,24,30),$ and $(15,36,39).$ See my comment to the question.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks, fixed. Though this 1-rep OP is not likely to come back.

Answer (score 0):

We begin with Euclid's formula as $\qquad A=m^2-k^2\quad B=2mk \quad C=m^2+k^2\quad$

$$R=\frac{area}{perimeter}=\frac{AB}{2P}=\frac{2mk(m^2-k^2)}{2(2m^2+2mk)}=\frac{mk-k^2}{2}$$

We can solve the ratio formula for $k$ and test a finite range of $m$-values to see which, if any yield integers.

\begin{equation}
R=\frac{mk-k^2}{2}\implies k=\frac{m\pm\sqrt{m^2-8R}}{2}\\\text{for}\quad\big\lceil\sqrt{8R}\big\rceil\le m \le (2R+1)
\end{equation}
The lower limit insures that $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and the upper limit ensures that $m> k$.

$$R=3\implies  \lceil\sqrt{8\cdot3}\space\rceil=5\le m \le (6+1)=7 
\\ \text{and we find}\quad   m\in\{ 5\}\implies k\in\{ 3,2\}
\quad\land \quad   m\in\{ 7\}\implies k\in\{ 6,1\}$$

$$
 f(5,3)=(16,30,34)\qquad \frac{16\cdot30}{2(16+30+34)}=\frac{480}{2(80)}=3\\
 f(5,2)=(21,20,29)\qquad \frac{21\cdot20}{2(21+20+29)}=\frac{420}{2(70)}=3\\
 f(7,6)=(13,84,85)\qquad\frac{13\cdot84}{2(13+84+85)}=\frac{1092}{2(182)}=3\\
 f(7,1)=(48,14,50)\qquad\frac{48\cdot14}{2(48+14+50)}=\frac{672}{2(112)}=3$$